# LDAP -samba problems with setup

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, ldapconnection

``I am done with setting up phpldapadmin , creating  OU , CN ,  ... different users
  and i can login the ldap users  from  different computer

Currently  I am working on ldap-samba   and  using this link:

- *http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1683595*

I m stuck at this point:

```
net getlocalsid
```

Here I get error  as follows:

```
[2012/02/08 15:37:23,  0] passdb/secrets.c:71(secrets_init)

  Failed to open /var/lib/samba/secrets.tdb

[2012/02/08 15:37:23,  0] passdb/secrets.c:71(secrets_init)

  Failed to open /var/lib/samba/secrets.tdb

[2012/02/08 15:37:23,  0] passdb/secrets.c:914(fetch_ldap_pw)

  fetch_ldap_pw: neither ldap secret retrieved!

[2012/02/08 15:37:23,  0] lib/smbldap.c:1046(smbldap_connect_system)




  ldap_connect_system: Failed to retrieve password from secrets.tdb

[2012/02/08 15:37:24,  0] passdb/secrets.c:71(secrets_init)

  Failed to open /var/lib/samba/secrets.tdb


[2012/02/08 15:37:24,  0] passdb/secrets.c:71(secrets_init)

  Failed to open /var/lib/samba/secrets.tdb

[2012/02/08 15:37:24,  0] passdb/secrets.c:914(fetch_ldap_pw)

  fetch_ldap_pw: neither ldap secret retrieved!
```

---

Here the log details :

```
[2012/02/08 14:05:18,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 3 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:19,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 4 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:20,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 5 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:21,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 6 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:22,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 7 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:23,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 8 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:24,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 9 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:25,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 10 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:26,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 11 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:27,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 12 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:28,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 13 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:29,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 14 try!

[2012/02/08 14:05:30,  1] lib/smbldap.c:1265(another_ldap_try)

  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 15 try!
```

I am lost  can any one  help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is old, but I had this and fixed it.

You need to make sure the hosts file contains an entry for your domain when you first install openLDAP (this is on the OpenLDAP page.  https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html) this then creates the entries for the domain which you can then use later.

There are however a lot of other problem with that tutorial on 12.04. Worth collecting them here for someone to google

smbldap_tools.pm is broken you will need to follow the instructions at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1988204

configure.pl is missing from smbldaptools https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/smbldap-tools/+bug/1006272 you will need to find one from somewher, I took one from an old installation on 10.04, whihc may (or may not) have caused the next problem

the uid/gid pairs are not properly separated from those used by ubuntu on install (i.e. the sudo user you create at install is    re-used for the first ldap user you add). This is I think down to https://mail.gna.org/public/smbldap-tools-tech/2011-09/msg00000.html    whihc is also    https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/smbldap-tools/+bug/531257 I    haven't managed to find a way round this yet.

Finally in order to make sense of things at the linux level you probably want it to see the ldap users as well, so you should follow this tutorial afterwards    https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication